# PHP: Flattening 1 Dimensional array into a spaced string

Tags: php, arrays

After much search (and finding endless posts about multidims, but no single dims) I thought I'd ask this question.

I have an array

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar');
```

and am looking for an output of

```
$str = 'foo bar';
```

This MUST be a one liner, no recursive loops etc etc etc, I am thinking that its going to have to be a lambda of some sort or another. This array will NEVER have more than a single key and a single value though.

I think its going to end up looking something like

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar');
echo 'Authorization: '  . array_walk($arr, function ($v, $k) { echo "$k $v"; });
```

which unfortunately ends up as `foo barAuthorization: 1`

no idea where the 1 comes from =P

Comment: *"no idea where the 1 comes from"* : `array_walk` returns a Boolean value, in your case `true` which is converted to `1` upon string concatenation. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php.

Comment: oh you want pairs to string...

Comment: your array_walk is outputting the pairs; you want it to create the string and return it instead.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need this in one line?

Comment: @popnoodles Its a direct input into a curlopt httpheader request

Comment: Why are you using `echo` if it needs to go into the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be quite easy since the array was just initialized and the pointer resides at the beginning of the array:

```
echo 'Authorization: ' . key($arr) . ' ' . current($arr);
```

Of course if you have already read data from the array you would want to do a `reset()` before doing this to return the pointer to the beginning of the array.

Comment: Yep works great, waiting to accept =) I forgot that `key()` existed

Answer (score -1):

PHP processes the function before it processes the string in front of it. Try replacing `echo` in your function with `return`. I think the 1 comes from the successfull processing of the array_walk function.

```
echo 'Authorization: '  . array_walk($arr, function ($v, $k) { return "$k $v"; });
```

UPDATE: Check out Example#1 http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: The return value of the callback is just ignored. `array_walk` *always* returns a Boolean.

Comment: Then he should iterate over the function with a foreach or something I guess.

Answer (score -3):

"This array will NEVER have more than a single key and a single value though"

```
echo 'Authorization: '  .  array_shift(array_keys($arr)). ' ' . array_shift($arr) ;
```